# iOS Certain Octal Escape Sequences Cause nil for stringWithUTF8String

Tags: iphone, ios, unicode

Our code calls `stringWithUTF8String` but some data we have uses an `octal` sequence \340 in the string. This causes some code to break because we never expect the function to return `nil`. I did some research and found that any octal sequence from \200-\777 will give the same result. I know I can handle this returning `nil` but I want to understand why it would return `nil`, and what those octal escapes are interpreted as.

```
NSString *result = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"Mfile \340 xyz.jpg"];
```

running this code return `nil` for result. It appears that to code defensively we will have to check null results for this everywhere where we use it which seems unfortunate. The documentation for the function does not say anything about returning nil as a possibility. I would bet that there is a lot of code out there that does not check for it either.

Comment: I ran this and it seemed to present the ` mark instead of `\140` instead of a `nil` string.

Comment: Sorry cut and paste error, i was playing with other values. Fixing should be \340 not \140

Comment: Added an answer. Take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a category which is called safeStringWithUTF8String: this is called everywhere instead it simply checks the return value for nil and returns the empty string if not valid. Not great but not sure what else to do we have to be able to handle any data passed in.

Answer (score 2):

The [`UTF-8 Character Table`](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=oct) doesn't have an entry for `\340`. You need to use the `ASCII` encoding for this. Do,

```
NSString * result = [NSString stringWithCString:"Mfile \340 xyz.jpg" encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want iOS to handle it as UTF-8 you have to make sure it's valid UTF-8 characters you pass to it, so you may need to convert the octal characters to something human readable first.

Comment: Oups, you're completely right - that comes from being to fast on the keyboard.